# is one hot encoding is free of the dummy trap

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, bigdata, data-science

there is a thing called dummy trap in one hot encoder that is when we encode the categorical column with 3 categories lest say a,b,and c then with one hot encoder we get 3 categories like or columns a, b ,and c but when we use get_dummies we get 2 columns instead a, and b then it is save from dummy trap. is one hot encoding exposed to dummy trap or it takes care of it . am i right? which one is save of dummy trap? or is it ok to use both with our removing columns, iam using the dataset for many algorithms.

looking for help . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OneHotEncoder` cannot process string values directly. If your nominal features are strings, then you need to first map them into integers.

`pandas.get_dummies` is kind of the opposite. By default, it only converts string columns into one-hot representation, unless columns are specified.

Comment: @Hendouzyou are right in this case, what i want to know is that do they care dummy trap or we have to remove one variable after encoding

Comment: Sorry but could you declare in a clear way what you mean by 'dummy trap'

Comment: @ HENDOUZ what i mean is, for instance in a get_dummies, there is a parameter called pd.get_dummies(df.Age, prefix, 'age').iloc[:,1] in this way we drop the first variable, so that we dont have any problem. how about in oneHot encoding, how we can drop the first varaible after encoding. how about the new variables name, does it get replaced with number values?